# Wrap a span around link text with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to dynamically wrap the text in my menu links with spans if the parent element has a certain class.

What I have:

```
<div class="mt-menu-container block">
    <ul id="menu" class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled">
        <li><a href="#">MenuItem</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I want to do is, if the parent element on line 1 has the class "block" I would like the text "MenuItem" in the  to be wrapped with spans so I get something like this:

```
<div class="mt-menu-container block">
    <ul id="menu" class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled">
        <li><a href="#"><span>MenuItem</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I tried is (Please don't laugh):

```
// Menu Block Style
if (jQuery('mt-menu-container.block')) {
   $('#menu > li > a').each(
       function(){
           $(this).wrap('<span></span>');
       });
}
```

Which didn't work since it's probably wrong on so many levels but you'll get the gist of it

Comment: `if (jQuery('.mt-menu-container.block')) {` you forgot the first dot `.` for classes.

Comment: @Doodlebunch and that will return exactly the same results since `if( jQueryObject)` is always truthy regardless if selector has matches or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery has the hasClass function. So to verify it an element has a certain class just use:

```
$('.mt-menu-container').each(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('block')) {
    $(this).find('a').each(function(){
      $(this).wrapInner('<span></span>');

    });      
  }
});
```

Comment: I believe that's the right way to go but I still can't get the text wrapped in spans

Comment: I edited my code, I think it should work, but it's not tested.

Comment: That works but instead of wrapping just the text it wraps the whole <a></a> so it turns out like this <span><a>MenuItem</a></span> instead of <a><span>MenuItem</span></a>

Comment: I understood wrong what you wanted. Use wrapInner instead of wrap. I edited the code.

Comment: The `if` is unnecessary, just include it in the selectors (if nothing is matched then nothing will happen): `$('.mt-menu-container.block #menu > li > a').wrapInner('<span></span>');`

Answer (score 0):

try:
`if (jQuery('mt-menu-container').hasClass('.block'))` istead of `if (jQuery('.mt-menu-container.block'))`